# RAM usage goes up linearly during model training. How to avoid this?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

Training a siamese neural network with semi-hard batching, RAM usage increases linearly over epochs, peaking at 60GB, then switches from GPU to CPU, slowing down training. I'm using Windows with an Ubuntu VM via Docker and Jupiter notebooks.
RAM issue persists in Docker even with reduced batch size on RTX 4090.

Hyperparams

```
batch_size = 16
epochs = 10
steps_per_epoch = int(x_train.shape[0]/batch_size)
val_steps = int(x_test.shape[0]/batch_size)
alpha = 0.2
num_hard = int(batch_size * 0.5) # Number of semi-hard triplet examples in the batch
lr = 0.00006
optimiser = 'Adam'
emb_size = 10
```

Hard Batch Creator

```
def create_hard_batch(batch_size, num_hard, split="train"):
    
    # Adjust for color images: width x height x depth
    x_anchors = np.zeros((batch_size, x_train_w, x_train_h, x_train_d))
    x_positives = np.zeros((batch_size, x_train_w, x_train_h, x_train_d))
    x_negatives = np.zeros((batch_size, x_train_w, x_train_h, x_train_d))
    
    if split == "train":
        data = x_train
        data_y = y_train
    else:
        data = x_test
        data_y = y_test
    
    # Generate num_hard number of hard examples:
    hard_batches = [] 
    batch_losses = []
    
    rand_batches = []
    
    # Get some random batches
    for i in range(0, batch_size):
        hard_batches.append(create_batch(1, split))  # Adjusted create_batch function for color images
        
        A_emb = embedding_model.predict(hard_batches[i][0])
        P_emb = embedding_model.predict(hard_batches[i][1])
        N_emb = embedding_model.predict(hard_batches[i][2])
        
        # Compute d(A, P) - d(A, N) for each selected batch
        batch_losses.append(np.sum(np.square(A_emb-P_emb),axis=1) - np.sum(np.square(A_emb-N_emb),axis=1))
    
    # Sort batch_loss by distance, highest first, and keep num_hard of them
    hard_batch_selections = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(batch_losses,hard_batches), key=lambda x: x[0])]
    hard_batches = hard_batch_selections[:num_hard]
    
    # Get batch_size - num_hard number of random examples
    num_rand = batch_size - num_hard
    for i in range(0, num_rand):
        rand_batch = create_batch(1, split)  # Adjusted create_batch function for color images
        rand_batches.append(rand_batch)
    
    selections = hard_batches + rand_batches
    
    for i in range(0, len(selections)):
        x_anchors[i] = selections[i][0]
        x_positives[i] = selections[i][1]
        x_negatives[i] = selections[i][2]
        
    return [x_anchors, x_positives, x_negatives]
```

Data Generator

```
def data_generator(batch_size=16, num_hard=50, split="train"):
    while True:
        x = create_hard_batch(batch_size, num_hard, split)
        y = np.zeros((batch_size, 3*emb_size))
        yield x, y
```

Training Function

```
siamese_history = siamese_net.fit_generator(
    data_generator(batch_size, num_hard),
    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    epochs=epochs,
    verbose=1,
    callbacks=callbacks, 
    workers=0, 
    validation_data=data_generator(batch_size, num_hard, split="test"), 
    validation_steps=val_steps);
```

RAM issue persists even with reduced batch size on RTX 4090.
Tried siamese_net.fit_generator() instead of siamese_net.fit(), no change.

Comment: You haven't asked any question.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I'm trying to avoid the RAM usage from going up during training. I updated the title.

Comment: `fit_generator` is deprecated since TF version 2.1.0. You can use `fit` with generators in TF. Maybe this solves your problem.

Comment: Does the memory usage keep increasing (memory leak)? Or are you just concerned that the think is too memory intense?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I believe it's a memory leak.